# What are good Sans-Serif fonts for technical documentation (printed and from monitor) where characters differ from each other?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

What are good Sans-Serif fonts for technical documentation (printed and from the monitor) where "I" (big i), "l" (small L), "1" (one), "!", "i", "j"  look different and also other characters differ from each other?

Comment: This question is very broad. There are many, many fonts that fit this criteria (such as [Source Sans Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans-pro)). Do you have specific needs? For example, are you putting in a lot of code snippets or math figures? What fonts have you tried and what didn't you like about them. As this question is written, it would only generate opinion answers.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39543

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic OS sans serif fonts like:

Verdana

[image: Verdana]
Tahoma

[image: Tahoma]

[Noto Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans) from Google Fonts

[image: Noto]

[Nubian](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/g-type/nubian/) from Myfonts.com

[image: Nubian]

Comment: Nice fonts. Thank you. I also found IBM Plex and Nubian fonts.